# Recommend a website for creating geometric figures

Tags: geometry, software

For teaching geometry, it could be useful to have a website where one can enter the names of vertices of a polygon, specify which diagonals should be depicted, and specify the measures of certain angles, and have the website generate a credible figure.

What are some likely websites for this purpose, and what are their strengths or weaknesses for use in the classroom or mathematics lab?

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: @Aeryk A teacher in my building recommended that. But I don't get it. You have to drag points to do it by hand, and I worked for a long time and failed to get the figure I want. There should be a way of typing in the desired values, rather than dragging. It should be one minute's work to create a figure as I described in the question.

Comment: Make yourself familiar with geogebra's command line. It's quite powerful.

Comment: Geogebra and Geometer's Sketchpad are some of the ones used most frequently in schools. That said, you may wish to check the more recent extension of Desmos to this area: https://www.desmos.com/geometry

Comment: You can definitely use Geogebra without manually dragging.  In addition to the command line, the various construction tools can usually be used to create a polygon to your exact specifications without ever dragging anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear to me how this is a question about mathematics education.  Rather, it appears to be a request for software recommendations for *doing* mathematics.  It *might* be appropriate on [math.se], but I suspect that some additional context would be required there, too.

Comment: I edited this because I think that the comments alone show there are plenty of teaching-oriented answers to what the essential question is here, even if it was formulated somewhat poorly.  I hope this would be enough for reconsider the close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer; just a tangential remark.
In general it is not an easy problem to reconstruct a
polygon from various sets of data. If the data does not
uniquely determine the polygon, it would not be easy 
to "generate a credible figure," to quote the OP, compatible
with the partial reconstruction.

For example, the paper below reconstructs a polygon from its "visibility angles," which do uniquely determine the polygon.

> Chen, Danny Z., and Haitao Wang. "An improved algorithm for reconstructing a simple polygon from the visibility angles." In *International Symposium on Algorithms and Computation*, pp. 604-613. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2011.
>   [Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772112000181).

---

[image: Rec1] [image: Rec2]

          

<sup>Fig. 1: Visibility angles at a vertex $v$. & Fig. 3.</sup>

---

Polygon reconstruction problems arise from the need for
a mobile robot to navigate an environment using sensor/scanner measurements to avoid wall collisions. The
Chen-Wang paper above cites 10 papers exploring 
a variety of reconstruction problems.